# NoMethodError on a form create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting a weird error after adding `<%= f.input :schedule, as: :datetime, input_html: {id: 'schedule'} %>` inorder to add a datetime selector.
I am wondering, what could the problem be?

`NoMethodError in Messages#new`
and 
``` undefined method ``schedule' for #<Message:0x000000066fa1e8> ```

my create controller is

```
def create
@lists = current_user.lists.all
@message = Message.new(params[:message])
lists = params[:message][:lists]
schedule = params[:message][:schedule]

if @message.save
  if schedule == [""]
    MessageWorker.perform_async(@message.id, lists, current_user.id)
  else
    Schedule.create(execution_time: schedule, lists: lists, message_id: @message_id, user_id: current_user.id)
  end

else
    render action: "new"
    flash[:notice] = "Messages Not Sent"
end

end
```

and the view is;

```
<%= simple_form_for(@message, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :from, placeholder: "Max 11 characters" , input_html: {id: 'sms_from'} %>
    <%= f.input :to, :input_html => {:value => params[:to], :class => "to"}, placeholder: "Separate Numbers with Comma", hint: "Include atleast one number in this section. Separate the  numbers with commas." %>

    <div id="add_lists"> <span class="button"> Add List </span></div>

    <div id="all_lists"> <%= f.collection_check_boxes :lists,  @lists, :id, :name, as: :select %></div>
    <%= f.input :message, :as => :text, :input_html => {:cols => 60, :rows => 7, id: "compose_message", placeholder: 'Type your message here!'} %>

    <div>
      <p>
          <span id="char_count">160 characters left</span>
          <span id="number_of_messages">1 message(s)</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <%= f.input :schedule, as: :datetime, input_html: {id: 'schedule'} %>
    <%= f.input :user_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => @current_user.id} %>
    <%= f.input :status, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => "Queued"} %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Send Message" %>
  <% end %>
```

and the model top looks like this;

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :message, :phone, :status, :to, :from, :user_id, :schedule
validates :message, :presence => true
validates :from, :presence => true
validates :to, :presence => true
validates :status, :presence => true
validates_length_of :message, :maximum => 1600, :allow_blank => true
validates_length_of :from, :maximum => 11, :allow_blank => false
belongs_to :user
```

Everything was working well until i added;

`<%= f.input :schedule, as: :datetime, input_html: {id: 'schedule'} %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you migrate the database to add the schedule column?

Or if you are not storing :schedule in the database, then you need to add:

```
attr_accessor :schedule
```

to your Message model.

Comment: Actually the `:schedule` in the message model is just a rush fix. i do not intend to stored the schedule field because am saving in the Schedule model db

Comment: Then attribute_accessor :schedule in the model perhaps?

Comment: You need to add:

`attr_accessor :schedule`

To your Message model

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `f.input`, you can use `f.date_field` of `f.datetime_field` as outlined in the API: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-date_field

Also, you don't have to use the form helper in this way as you can use `datetimefield_tag` instead of `f.datetime_field` as outlined here http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper:datetime_field_tag